# stable alternative to apt-get in scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, github

`apt-get` gives the following warning when some of the commands below are run by a GitHub Action on an Ubuntu-lastest GitHub runner:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

What else should be used instead of `apt-get` to do the same things that the following commands do on the Ubuntu-latest GitHub runner?

```
    sudo apt install -y dos2unix
    sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
    sudo apt clean
```

We originally just ignored the warning message above.  But last night a lot of our jobs on those Ubuntu-latest runners returned wonky results, and some of the broken jobs had the `apt-get warning` shown above.  We do not currently have last night's wonky logs to post here.  But we want to prevent unpredictable intermittent wonky behavior.

Is there a better alternative to `apt-get` to use for scripts?

Comment: Uh do you mean `apt-get` per your text or `apt` per your examples? You seem to be confusing them

Answer (score 1):

You should use `apt-get` instead of `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dos2unix
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
```

This is explained in [the `apt` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/apt/apt.8.en.html#SCRIPT_USAGE_AND_DIFFERENCES_FROM_OTHER_APT_TOOLS):

> The `apt(8)` commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may change behavior between versions. While it tries not to break backward compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial for interactive use.
>
> All features of `apt(8)` are available in dedicated APT tools like `apt-get(8)` and `apt-cache(8)` as well. `apt(8)` just changes the default value of some options (see `apt.conf(5)` and specifically the Binary scope). So you should prefer using these commands (potentially with some additional options enabled) in your scripts as they keep backward compatibility as much as possible.

Comment: Why in particular?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I agree with this advice.  I've been seeing a lot of instructions the past year or two giving `apt` commands instead of `apt-get` ones, and wondered if `apt-get` were being deprecated.